# How to match part of rows in different tables with each other in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, match, tld

I have a table called 'urls' which contains domain name of different countries like below:

```
Domain
Paypal.com
wellsfargo.co.uk
sparkasse.fe.de
```

etc...

and I have another table called 'country' which contains tlds and their associated country like below:

```
tld        country
nl          netherlands
de          germany
uk          united kingdom
etc...
```

I do not know how can I create a match in which I would be able to extract the name of the country in the table 'country' from domains in table 'urls'.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables with the following `JOIN` condition:

```
ON ( country.tld = RIGHT(urls.domain, CHAR_LENGTH(tld)) )
```

Notice this query couldn't use an index on `urls.domain`, if such an index exists. I would precompute the top-level domain of `urls.domain` on insertion in a separate column (in  `urls`). Set an index on this new column, and use this column in your `JOIN` condition.